# while loop to check status end in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying the following loop to get the status return and recall the command cmd until status=0
but this is not working as I expect it to.
What do you think about the following code :

```
[status,message] = system(cmd);
 while status==false
      disp('the return value is not correct');
               [status,message] = system(cmd);
                if status == 0
                    break;

               end
  end
```

Comment: Any hints as to what isn't working? Are you stuck inside the loop indefinitely?

Comment: What is the command you are trying to execute by `cmd`. Is it actually the Windows command prompt or another command ? Also `0` and `false` will be interpreted the same by matlab, so your `while status==false` condition will only run one time, because within the loop you are also saying `if status == 0 ; break;`

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to run cmd until you get a 0 (false) return, therefore, what you should do is:

```
[status,message] = system(cmd);
 while status~=false
      disp('the return value is not correct');
      [status,message] = system(cmd);
 end
```

So it will keep iterating until status == false

Comment: That doesn't compute. Why would you return `'the return value is not correct'` if `status==true`?

Comment: Make up your mind. Looking at your code it is not possible to know what you exactly want. Change it to true then. I based on the assumption that usually a successful command returns 0 (success).

Comment: You're preaching to the choir m8, that isn't my code.

Comment: @sobek sorry I did not realize that you were not OP hehe.  I just updated the logic, not the semantic meaning of the program.